# Built in microphone OK in Windows, but noisy in Ubuntu & not detected in Citrix Remote Desktop app

Tags: sound, lenovo, remote-desktop, microphone, citrix

My built in internal mic on laptop `Lenovo Ideapad 320` works fine while using Windows. But when I try to use it in Ubuntu, its performance is somewhat between **Properly working** and **Not working**. The microphone records my voice but when I hear my recordings, more that half of the sound is consists of noise which almost makes my voice unclear.

When I use my earphones mic instead of the internal mic, it works totally fine.

When I use a Citrix remote desktop app, it does not detect any mic, while Windows does this fine again.

*Lenovo Ideapad 320-15IKB (80XL)*

*Ubuntu Version: 18.04*

Comment: Lenovo ideapad 320-15IKB (7200U, 940MX, FHD), am I correct?

Comment: Type 80XL, 80YE, https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/320-15ikb/documentation 81BG, or 81BT https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/320-15ikb-type-81bg-81bt/documentation

Comment: Lenovo ideapad 320-15IKB 80XL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Citrix application is not very user friendly on Linux systems. I had the same problem with the Citrix app. Try adding the following line to ~/.ICAClient/wfclient.ini:

```
[WFClient]
AllowAudioInput=True
```